# C#: How to change the color of specific lines in a chart?

Tags: c#, charts

I do not want to change the whole series like this:

```
chart1.Series["test1"].Color = Color.Red;
```

Instead, I want to change the color of individual lines, like this:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var r = new Random();
    int i = chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY(r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10));

    try
    {
        chart1.Series["test1"].Points[i - 1].Color = Color.LightPink;
        chart1.Series["test1"].Points[i - 2].Color = Color.LightPink;
        chart1.Series["test1"].Points[i - 3].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart1.Series["test1"].Points[i - 4].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
         chart1.Series["test1"].Points.RemoveAt(i - 5);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

However, this is not working and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the SeriesChartType was set to FastLine instead of just Line.

This doesn't work:

```
chart1.Series["test1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
```

This works:

```
chart1.Series["test1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```